# how to design a tableview in android app

Tags: android, user-interface

I found the following design in market of my tablet. I want to design a layout as like the below tables containing a image, text and a button for my android app. how to do this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve simple table look, by setting different colors to rows and cloumns and set appropriate margins in that here is [example](http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/how-to-display-border-lines-with-tablelayouts/). Here he sets only border but you can fill any color or drawable inside column.

Answer (score 1):

For this solution, i would suggest you to design custom adapter to be displayed either in GridView or in multi column ListView.

But i think [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) would be best to implement the above functionality.

Now, to define a custom adapter, you just have to create a simple class and extends BaseAdapter, and then you have to override the getView() method inside this class. Now within the getView() method, you can inflate() the custom row layout file (which you define for one item , this item xml layout file represents every items inside the GridView).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) is the simple example for implementing a simple GridView.

[image]

For the detailed exmmple of such gridview, refer this example: [Android - GridView example](http://www.technotalkative.com/?p=1476)

Comment: i have a problem in using grid view.In the tablet this part comes in the middle and for the whole page i have a scroll view. In the grid i am going to show only 6 datas. The overall scroll is not working... so any choice other than grid view.....

Comment: @SivaK have you designed layout specific for the tablet layout, and why it's coming in middle, haven't you checked why?